# Solving ODE using Laplace Transforms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Given function:

$$y''-2y'+5y=e^t$$

where $y(\pi)=2$ and $y'(\pi)=3$

I've got my inverse Laplace Transform as:

$\frac{1}{4}e^tcos(2t)+\frac{1}{4}e^t+y(0)e^tcos(2t)-1*e^tsin(2t)+y'(0)e^t\frac{1}{2}sin(2t)$

How should I use the initial conditions given from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(t)=\frac{1}{4}e^t\cos(2t)+\frac{1}{4}e^t+y(0)e^t\cos(2t)-e^t\sin(2t)+y'(0)e^t\frac{1}{2}\sin(2t)$$
Rewrite as: 
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{4}e^t\cos(2t)+\frac{1}{4}e^t+c_1e^t\cos(2t)-e^t\sin(2t)+c_2e^t\frac{1}{2}\sin(2t)$$
 Then apply first initial condition: 
$$f(\pi)=\frac{1}{2}e^{\pi}+c_1e^{\pi}=2$$
$$ \implies c_1=?$$
Differentiate $f(t)$ and apply second initial condition.

---

You can also rewrite $f(t)$ more simply as:
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{4}e^t+k_1e^t\cos(2t)+k_2e^t\sin(2t)$$
And:
$$f'(t)=\frac{1}{4}e^t+(k_1+2k_2)e^t\cos(2t)+(k_2-2k_1)e^t\sin(2t)$$

---

**Edit2:**

You find:
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{4}e^t\cos(2t)+\frac{1}{4}e^t+\frac{2-\frac{1}{2}e^t}{e^t}*e^t\cos(2t)-1*e^t\sin(2t)+\frac{1+2e^t}{e^t}*e^t*\frac{1}{2}\sin(2t)$$
It should be :
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{4}e^t\cos(2t)+\frac{1}{4}e^t+\frac{2-\frac{1}{2}e^{\pi}}{e^{\pi}}*e^t\cos(2t)-1*e^t\sin(2t)+\frac{1+2e^{\pi}}{e^{\pi}}*e^t*\frac{1}{2}\sin(2t)$$

You see the difference ? The coefficients $c_1,c_2$ have $\pi$ and the functions keep their $t$ variable. Now if you check $f({\pi})=2$ it looks correct to me. Simplify:
$$\boxed {f(t)=\frac{1}{4}e^t+\left (\frac 2 {e^{\pi}}-\dfrac 14 \right )e^t\cos(2t)+\frac{e^t}{2e^{\pi}}\sin(2t)}$$

Comment: By applying first initial condition, you mean to substitute $\pi$ into $t$?

Comment: After applying first initial condition, is it right that I get, $2=\frac{1}{4}e^(\pi)cos(2\pi)+\frac{1}{4}e^(\pi)+c_1e^(\pi)cos(2\pi)-1*e^(\pi)sin(2\pi)+c_2e^(\pi)\frac{1}{2}sin(2\pi)$?

Comment: Do you consider $sin(2\pi)$ as $0$?

Comment: Then would $c_1=\frac{4-e^\pi}{2e^\pi}$?

Comment: I got $c_2=\frac{1+2e^\pi}{e^\pi}$. Then I substitute in the calculated values into $f(t)$ right?

Comment: Then final solution would be $\frac{1}{4}e^tcos(2t)+\frac{1}{4}e^t+\frac{2-\frac{1}{2}e^t}{e^t}*e^tcos(2t)-1*e^tsin(2t)+\frac{1+2e^t}{e^t}*e^t*\frac{1}{2}sin(2t)$?

Comment: How can I verify if my final solution is correct or not?

Comment: Yes. Then final solution would be as $\frac{1}{4}e^t+\frac{2-\frac{1}{2}e^\pi}{e^\pi}e^tcos(2t)+\frac{1+2e^\pi}{e^\pi}e^tsin(2t)$

Comment: Then it would be as $f(\pi)=\frac{1}{4}e^\pi+\frac{2-\frac{1}{2}e^\pi}{e^\pi}(e^\pi)cos(2\pi)+\frac{1+2e^\pi}{e^\pi}e^tsin(2\pi)$?

Comment: The final solution should be in terms of $\pi$? or is it correct with the terms of t? There was a comment before about it.

Comment: I get as result $f(\pi)=\frac{1}{2}e^\pi+2$ @Aryadeva